# What to put hexadecimal data in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I am putting data in a dictionary. I want to classify data per source adress. My data template look like this:

```
(timestamp, idsource,iddest, counter)
```

This is an example of my data:

```
('1547911869', '02141592cc00000002', '02141592cc00000001', '1'), 
('1547911869', '02141592cc00000003', '02141592cc00000004', '2'), 
('1547911869', '02141592cc00000004', '02141592cc00000005', '4'),
```

in order to put them in a dictionary, I uuse these lines:

```
for timestamp, id_src_node ,id_dest_node ,Counter in list_info:
    if init_time == None:
        init_time = float(timestamp)

    if id_src_node not in dict_node_info:
        dict_node_info[id_src_node] = {"timestamp": [float(timestamp) - init_time], 'Counter': [int(1)], 'ID_Dest':[int(id_dest_node)]}
    else:
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["timestamp"].append(float(timestamp) - init_time)
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["Counter"].append(int(1))
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["Counter"].append(int(id_dest_node))

return dict_node_info
```

But this strategy gives me this error:

```
dict_node_info[id_src_node] = {"timestamp": [float(timestamp) - init_time], 'Counter': [int(1)], 'ID_Dest':[int(id_dest_node)]}
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '01ffff00ffffffffffffffffb00abeff'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in create an integer from a hexidecimal string? if you do truely want to convert your hex string to an int then you have to tell int that its hex value. like `int('FF', 16)`  will assign the value `255`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert your hex inputs to ints you need to tell int that the input is in base 16, as by default it will assume base 10.

```
for timestamp, id_src_node ,id_dest_node ,Counter in list_info:
    if init_time == None:
        init_time = float(timestamp)

    if id_src_node not in dict_node_info:
        dict_node_info[id_src_node] = {"timestamp": [float(timestamp) - init_time], 'Counter': [int(1)], 'ID_Dest':[int(id_dest_node, 16)]}
    else:
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["timestamp"].append(float(timestamp) - init_time)
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["Counter"].append(int(1))
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["Counter"].append(int(id_dest_node, 16))

return dict_node_info
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because you're trying to convert an hexadecimal string into an `int base 10`.
Basically your code goese through this part of code:

```
>> a = '01ffff00ffffffffffffffffb00abeff'
>> int(a)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '01ffff00ffffffffffffffffb00abeff'
```

So, like you can see you got a `ValueError`.

So, one way to bypass this problem is to create a handy function that checks if the passed string if it's a valid `int` or it contains an hexadecimal.

So, you can do something linke this:

```
def to_int(elm):
    """
    Need to check if there is another exceptions may occure 
    during the conversion of strings into integers
    """
    try:
        return int(elm)
    except ValueError:
        return int(elm, 16)


for timestamp, id_src_node ,id_dest_node ,Counter in list_info:
    if init_time == None:
        init_time = float(timestamp)

    if id_src_node not in dict_node_info:
        dict_node_info[id_src_node] = {"timestamp": [float(timestamp) - init_time], 'Counter': [int(1)], 'ID_Dest':[to_int(id_dest_node)]}
    else:
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["timestamp"].append(float(timestamp) - init_time)
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["Counter"].append(int(1))
        dict_node_info[id_src_node]["Counter"].append(to_int(id_dest_node))

return dict_node_info
```